# TextArea hanging after switchView in iOS only

Tags: ios, textarea, gluon-mobile

Good morning everybody working with Gluon Mobile

I have the problem of a javafx.scene.control.TextArea staying on the screen like a layer after switching the view, that is, after calling

```
Application.getInstance().switchView(...)
```

from a screen with a TextField and this TextArea arranged inside a VBox (with consent from Gluon, I used the code from their Notes example). The isolated TextArea then appears as if it was layered over the other screen to which the switch took place.

This happens on the iPhone / iOS only, and only if the text area had the focus at least once. On the desktop as well as under Android, or when the focus was never in this TextArea, everything works fine.

Does anybody have an idea what could cause this effect?

Regards

Martin

Comment: It’s the combination of TextArea and TextField, and the fact that in iOS, these are implemented using the native layer, which cause the problem. The only workaround currently available seems to be using either TextArea only or TextField only.  I use IntelliJ IDEA Gluon Plugin 2.6.3 and jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.10.